# .otherwise or /** in the new Angular2 Router to route non-route through wild cards

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

How do i use wild cards to route when a non functional route is given in the new Router... like the ones  .otherwise in 1.X router or /** in previous beta router ? Any example / plnkr code is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

    const routes: RouterConfig = [
      { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    ];

    export const appRouterProviders = [
      provideRouter(routes)
    ];
```

> The ** denotes a wildcard path for our route. The
>   router will match this route if the URL requested doesn't match any
>   paths for routes defined in our configuration. This is useful for
>   displaying a 404 page or redirecting to another route.

Take a look at the router [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#configuration)

Comment: The info can be found more exactly on the [Configuration section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#configuration) of the link provided of the docs link, as well on the [RouterConfig API](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterConfig-type-alias.html#wild-cards) doc page.